# Scala: singleton object vs anonymous class

Tags: scala, singleton, anonymous-class

In Scala, an inner singleton object and an anonymous inner class seem to achieve the same end. What are the differences between them, and when should I prefer using one over the other?

Inner singleton object:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  object A {
    val a = 7
  }
  
  println(A.a)
}
```

Anonymous inner class:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  val A = new {
    val a = 7
  }
  
  println(A.a)
}
```

Comment: The second one is using reflection under the hood and is no longer valid as of **Scala 3** where you need to be explicit of the reflection access using `Selectable`

Comment: I suppose my example for the anonymous inner class does use reflection. However, not all uses of anonymous classes require reflection, so how do they differ from singleton objects in that case? Should I edit my question to not use reflection?

Comment: If you do something like `new Foo { ... }` and only access the members defined by `Foo` there is really not much difference other than the `lazy` loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one visible difference between them and I shall explain:

> An `object` behaves like a `lazy val`. In fact, it can be seen as a
> shorthand for the definition of a `lazy val` with an anonymous class
> which describes the `object`'s contents.

This description is taken directly from [Programming in Scala 4th Ed.](https://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_4ed) (Chapter 20. Abstract Members. Subchapter 20.5 Initializing abstract vals) by M. Odersky, B. Venners and L. Spoon.

Here is an example, that shows the difference:

```
object Program extends App {
  object Demo {
    val a = {
      println("initializing a from Demo")
      7
    }
  }

  val A = new {
    val a = {
      println("initializing a from A")
      8
    }
  }

  println(Demo.a)
  println(A.a)
}
```

Output:

```
initializing a from A
initializing a from Demo
7
8
```

As you can see, when you instantiate an anonymous class. `Val a` is evaluated before the reference `A` is initialized. That is not the same with `Demo`. `Val a` is only initialized where the object `Demo` is first used, and that is the line that prints it, not where it is defined.

You should use objects when you want to code in a more functional and/or be more efficient in terms of memory. Because objects are lazy evaluated, they get evaluated exactly when they are needed, if they are needed. If they aren't needed, they will not be evaluated. So you avoid a memory overhead right there, for example if the evaluation of the anonymous class is an compute-intensive operation, this can make a difference if you use a lot of them in an enterprise application.

Comment: This is a great answer. If you got this from somewhere else, will you please edit your answer to include a reference.

Comment: Edited and included reference to it.